# How to change my pandas dataframe output format such as auto adjust column size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I newly installyed pandas and python, and my pandas dataframe result is not like the usual type. I tried to upgrade pandas and ipython, but none of these worked.[This is my desired dataframe format for displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z79E4.png)

[This is what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGM87.png)

Comment: Post your code as text, not links to images, also post raw data that allows others to attempt to reproduce your issue

Comment: Could you please share program snippet for this above issue

Comment: The problem is not much related to code itself, but rather the version issue I believe. Thw two images are from two different computers. I don't know how to get pandas dataframe to be outputted without borders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200) # increase the number of visible columns in output to 200
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 200) # increase the number of visible rows in output to 200
```

**EDIT:**

Paste the following code in any cell and that should work for you:

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
border: none !important;
color: black !important;
}
</style>
```

[image: Styling for no borders can be done by using the HTML style tags]

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The problem is about styling. It is likely due to version difference, but I'm not sure what should I change.  I have 0.24.2 for pandas and 2.7 for python

Comment: @samwello, I have edited my answer for styling the dataframe without borders and auto adjusting the column width.

Comment: Your original myDF output is my desired output format. However, I currently only have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGM87.png